# Why does the object move when clearing its parent?

Tags: parent

[image]

When the parent-child binding is canceled, the geometry of the group of objects is broken. How can this be avoided or if this is not possible, corrected?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the problem, but if you're talking about objects shifting around after clearing parent (Alt+P) it's likely that transforms are not applied. So it that's the case either apply scale and rotation or when un-parenting choose the "Clear and keep transformation".
Otherwise it would be helpful if you could add some screenshots showing the problem.

Comment: thanks, was close to madness;)

Comment: Related for the script minded https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160580/15543

Answer (score 5):

As stated in my comment, I'm pretty sure you can fix this by using Alt+P and selecting "Clear and keep transformation". This way it should clear the parent and keep its location.

What happens in your example is that when you remove the parent like that, your object jumps back to the original location/rotation it was in before it was parented to something.

Comment: To be clear, it's not so much that it "remembers" where it was before being parented, but rather that the object coordinates (which have stayed numerically constant) are interpreted with respect to a coordinate system previously centered at the parent but now centered at the global origin.