# Why is my rotation method sometimes incorrect for parented objects

Tags: python, scripting, parent, coordinates

I wrote Python's function to rotate a object '**o**' direction, step by step, to '**directionW**' direction.

When the **o** has no parent, the function works great. But, when the **o** has one or more parent, function sometimes works correctly, sometimes wrong. When it works wrong the direction of **o** don't going to **directionW** by shortest way, but going in space by way (like 8-digit) around **directionW**.

Next is the function:

```
    def RotateToDirectionW( o, directionW, step, adaptivestep, maxunlock ):
    """o - object to step rotate to directionW"""
    """directionW - direction to achieve step by step (unit vector in world coordinates)"""
    """adaptivestep - if True, then rotation angle has minimal value when direction of o near to directionW,"""
    """maxunlock - maximal vector size to unlock, 1E-5 or 0"""

    matLtoW = o.matrix_world
    matWtoL = matLtoW.copy(); matWtoL.invert()
    if o.parent != None:
        matWtoP = o.parent.matrix_world.copy(); matWtoP.invert()
    else:
        matWtoP = Matrix.Identity(4)

    # direction of o ( axe z+ ) in world coordinates
    dirW = ( matLtoW @ Vector((0,0,1)) ) - ( matLtoW @ Vector((0,0,0)) )
    dirW.normalize()        # need to normalize angle

    # calculate axe, around what object will be rotated (in world c.)
    axeRotW = dirW.cross( directionW )
    
    power = axeRotW.length
    
    # unlock
    # if vector is too small to rotate, take any bigger
    if abs(power)<maxunlock:
        axeRotW = Vector( (maxunlock,maxunlock,maxunlock) )
        power = axeRotW.length

    # transform axe of rotation to parent base coordinates
    # (problem somewhere there)
    axeRotP = (matWtoP.to_quaternion() @ axeRotW

    if adaptivestep:
        angle = step * power
    else:
        angle = Vector.angle( dirW, directionW )
        if (angle > step): angle = step

    # rotation
    qutRot = Quaternion( axeRotP, angle )
    o.rotation_euler.rotate( qutRot )
```

I check every possible intermediate results, they are correct at all. The axe of rotation is correct in world space. I think, problem is when **axeRotW** converted to parent coordinate space. It look like there is transitional transformation between parent's transformation and **o** own transformation. I think, i need convert **axeRotW** to this transitional coordinate system, but there is no information about it.

What is a way to solve the problem? I waste several day of my time to do it, but now i into deadlock.

*P.S.:* I try, also, to rotate **o** by *bps.transform.rotate*(), but this operation can't work with custom rotation axe, XYZ-only.

*P.P.S.:* A founded 3 conditions for the correct result:

- 1. The object **o** has not parent
- 2. The object has parent object with identity (equal 1) 'matrix_parent_inverse'.
- 3. The object has parent 3-verticies with same direction of coordinates as parent, and identity 'matrix_parent_inverse'.

*P.P.P.S.:* To investigate matrix chain calculation, i run script from blender.stackexchange.com/a/160580/15543

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix

context = bpy.context
ob = context.active_object
M = Matrix()
print("==== calc word matrix ====")
print(ob.matrix_world)
while ob.parent:
    M = (ob.matrix_parent_inverse @ ob.matrix_basis) @ M
    ob = ob.parent

M = ob.matrix_basis @ M

print(M)
```

If generic child object was selected, then script prints two equal matrices. But, if somewhere in parent-child chain exists 3-vertices parenting, then the printed matrices was *different*!!!. F.e.:

```
---- calc word matrix ----
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.0198,  0.1843,  0.4570, 15.1996)
            ( 0.0012,  0.4574, -0.1844, -4.9117)
            (-0.4928, -0.0063, -0.0188,  3.4083)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>
<Matrix 4x4 (-0.0465, -0.2971,  1.1550, 36.2083)
            (-0.0120,  1.1559,  0.2969, 11.8968)
            (-1.1926,  0.0000, -0.0480,  1.8346)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.0000)>
```

It is possible, there is one addition transformation in parent-child chain. And i need to take into account yellow colored block:

[image: 3-vertices parenting add one extra transformation block]

How i see, there is no python access to extra v3-parenting transformation matrix. I suppose, with help of some math we can calculate this extra matrix. But how?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160580/15543  _ie_ it appears it is not being taken into account `ob.matrix_parent_inverse` may not be identity.

Comment: prob a better link https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169424/15543

Comment: I clear matrix_parent_inverse now, result is changed, but it not correct anymore.
Also i try next conversion: axeRotP = (matWtoP.to_quaternion() @ axeRotW)

Comment: Would also need to convert as well as clear.  Basically if the parent inverse is identity then local origin is at parent origin.  This is for a mesh but pertinent here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/183724/15543 in that aligning object to a face normal vector.  The quaternion rotation difference between vectors will calculate axis and angle.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. A founded 3 conditions for the correct result:

1. The object 'o' has not parent
2. The object has parent object with identity 'matrix_parent_inverse'.
3. The object has parent 3-verticies with same direction of coordinates as parent, and identity 'matrix_parent_inverse'.

How to take into account 'matrix_parent_inverse' - i don't understand. I try insert transformation with 'o.matrix_parent_inverse' in several places, but, without success. My guess how 'o.matrix_parent_inverse' works and how it works in real - is different.

Comment: Yes for 3 vertex parenting would need an  intermediary step to calculate  the origin and normal of 3 verts.  Suggest this is a new question.  Anyway back to your original question, IMO the logic is wrong.  Simply build a rotation matrix using `v1.rotational_difference(v2)`  see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/183724/15543

Comment: Big thanks again. Your examples is very useful.
The problem is coordinate transformation. I have correct rotation axe (**axeRotW**) in world coordinates. I can't transform the axe to desired coordinate system correctly.
To work with targetAxe.rotation_difference(currentAxe), it is needed to transform targetAxe to coordinate system where currentAxe is. And it is the same problem, what i have now.

Comment: How i understand from Your examples and my investigation, `matrix_world = parent.matrix_world * parent.matrix_x * matrix_parent_inverse * matrix_basis`. And matrix `matWtoB = (awR.matrix_world.inverted() @ awR.matrix_basis.inverted() ) @ awR.matrix_parent_inverse.inverted()` must do correct transformation, but not do.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
matrix_world = parent.matrix_world * parent.matrix_x * matrix_parent_inverse * matrix_basis
```

where **parent.matrix_x** is inaccessible matrix by python, we can't calculate **matWtoP** from o.parent (in common case) and must to use **o.matrix_word**. The right transformation is:

```
# transform axe of rotation to parent base coordinates
matWtoP = o.matrix_basis @ o.matrix_world.inverted()
axeRotP = matWtoP.to_quaternion() @ axeRotW
```

---

Most basic source of errors in my investigations above was a order of execution of @-operands in Blender. I had false representation about it and tried to use the order like `matWtoP = o.matrix_world.inverted() @ o.matrix_basis`, what is wrong.